# How to replace a background image in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a script where I'm going through a loop, and once a condition is met, an image is added to my Tkinter window. I'm able to add and resize the image in Tkinter, however what I want to do is replace the image (or rather, just add another image on top of the previous one), as I go through my while loop. However, while `Images` is redefined as 'greencar.jpg', the actual image is not posted in the window.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

Images=()
class Example(Frame):
    global Images
    def __init__(self, master, *pargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, *pargs)



        self.image = Image.open(Images)
        self.img_copy= self.image.copy()


        self.background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)

        self.background = Label(self, image=self.background_image)
        self.background.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
        self.background.bind('<Configure>', self._resize_image)

    def _resize_image(self,event):

        new_width = event.width
        new_height = event.height

        self.image = self.img_copy.resize((new_width, new_height))

        self.background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
        self.background.configure(image =  self.background_image)

def main():
    global Images
    x=0
    root.update_idletasks()
    while x<100000:
        x+=1
        if x == 500:
            Images='mountain.jpg'
            e = Example(root)
            e.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
            root.update_idletasks()

        if x == 5000:
            Images='greencar.jpg'
            e = Example(root)
            e.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
            root.update_idletasks()




root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('600x600')
main()
root.mainloop()
```

---

Edit:
So trying Saad's solution works really nicely, but I tried to extend it one step further, by implementing a couple of functions and a second loop.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

Images= "mountain.jpg"


class Example(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master, *pargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, *pargs)

        self.image = Image.open(Images)
        self.img_copy= self.image.copy()

        self.background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)

        self.background = Label(self, image=self.background_image)
        self.background.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
        self.background.bind('<Configure>', self._resize_image)

    def _resize_image(self,event):
        new_width = event.width
        new_height = event.height

        self.image = self.img_copy.resize((new_width, new_height))

        self.background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
        self.background.configure(image =  self.background_image)

    def change_image(self, file):
        """Change background image of the window."""
        size = (self.winfo_width(), self.winfo_height())
        self.image = Image.open(file).resize(size)
        self.background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
        self.background.configure(image=self.background_image)


def add(x):
    return x+3

def subtract(x):
    return x-1

def check_image(x=0):
    x=add(x)
    if x >= 1000:
        return # Break the loop
    if x == 50:
        e.change_image('mountain.jpg')
    elif x == 500:
        e.change_image('greencar.jpg')
    print(x)
    root.after(1, check_image,subtract(x))

def loop():
    while True:
        question=input('go again?')
        if question == 'n':
            break
        check_image(x=0)


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('600x600')
e = Example(root)
e.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
loop()
root.mainloop()
```

So what I wanted was the option for the user to go through the loop again. So I made another function to do this. However, `check_image()` no longer loops. It stops at the first iteration. If I break my while in `loop()` (by typing 'n'), then it will go through the `check_image()` iterations, however, the images no longer update. In short, I seem to have broken the program again, but I don't quite understand why.

Comment: Since you have used `pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)`, the second instance of `Example()` created when `x == 5000` is squeezed by the first instance of `Example()` created when `x == 500`.  You can see the second image being squeezed if you resize the root window manually.  Call `e.destroy()` before creating the second `Example()`.

Comment: Using a `while` loop or `for` loop will make the Tkinter application inactive till the loop ends that is why Tkinter has `after` method to do the same. Here in your `loop` function, instead of using while loop use `after` method. And I think it would be better if you add a Button or any bind to repeat the `check_image` function but also checking if it is currently running before calling another `change_image` function.

Comment: Oh I see. So I removed the ```while``` and now have ```if question == 'n': \n return \n check_image(x=0) \n root.after(1,loop)```. However, ```check_image``` only runs through 2 iterations now (x printout is 3 and 5), and while the Tkinter window pops up, the images never end up loading (the window just stays frozen loading). Additionally, so if you are using tkinter, you should never use a ```while``` loop, always use ```after``` instead?

Comment: @Saad sorry forgot to tag you in my reply

Comment: I forgot to mention `input` also makes the GUI inactive as it is waiting for a reply from the user. What you can do is [`bind`](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) key `y` *(means "yes")*  to the root window and use the `change_image` as a function callback. Ex: `bind('y', lambda event: change_image(0))` *(also check if the function is currently running before calling another)*.

Comment: But I want the GUI to wait for a response from the user. For example if I do: ```print('go again?')
    root.bind('y', lambda event: check_image(0))
    #root.bind('n', lambda event: #something to break the loop)
    root.after(1,loop)``` Then this will ```print('go again')``` indefinitely. If you click ```y```, then it will run through ```check_image(0)``` but once that is done it will run ```loop()``` indefinitely again. Furthermore, despite running through ```change_image(0)``` now, the pics are still not updated (the Tkinter window remains unchaged)

Comment: With `bind` i don't think if you even need `loop` function, as any time user wants to change the images again he/she can just press `y` key to do so. Also, I think you should ask a follow-up question with all the details regarding you issues and what exactly your goal is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218470/discussion-between-samman-and-saad).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code that needs to be addressed.

1. To replace the image you have to create a new instance of `PhotoImage` with `file='new_image.png'` argument every time and then `self.background.configure(image=new_image_instance)`. As in your `main` function, you are just creating a new `Example` widget in the same window.
2. I don't recommend using `update_idletasks()` in a while loop instead the whole while loop can be replaced by [`after(ms, func, *args)`](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) method of Tkinter.

   ```py
   def check_image(x=0):
       # Break the loop
       if x >= 100000: return
       if x == 500:
           e.change_image('mountain.jpg')
       elif x == 5000:
           e.change_image('greencar.jpg')
       root.after(1, check_image, x+1)
   ```
3. I think it would be best to just create a method that will change the image of the `Example` widget.

   ```py
   def change_image(self, file):
       """Change background image of the window."""
       size = (self.winfo_width(), self.winfo_height())
       self.image = Image.open(file).resize(size)
       self.background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
       self.background.configure(image=self.background_image)
   ```

*Complete Code:*

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

Images= "image.png"


class Example(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master, *pargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, *pargs)

        self.image = Image.open(Images)
        self.img_copy= self.image.copy()

        self.background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)

        self.background = Label(self, image=self.background_image)
        self.background.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
        self.background.bind('<Configure>', self._resize_image)

    def _resize_image(self,event):
        new_width = event.width
        new_height = event.height

        self.image = self.img_copy.resize((new_width, new_height))

        self.background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
        self.background.configure(image =  self.background_image)
    
    def change_image(self, file):
        """Change background image of the window."""
        size = (self.winfo_width(), self.winfo_height())
        self.image = Image.open(file).resize(size)
        self.background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
        self.background.configure(image=self.background_image)


def check_image(x=0):
    if x >= 100000: return # Break the loop
    if x == 500:
        e.change_image('mountain.jpg')
    elif x == 5000:
        e.change_image('greencar.jpg')
    root.after(1, check_image, x+1)
    

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('600x600')
e = Example(root)
e.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
check_image()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: For item 1, the two images are not overlapped since `pack()` is used.

Comment: @acw1668: Thank you for pointing it out I completely missed that.

Comment: This doesn't fit the image to the window size however.

Comment: @samman: Try now, I've edited the `change_image` function which will now take care of the size of the image to fit with the window.

Comment: @Saad One follow up question, how would I implement this if I wanted this to go through another loop? I have edited my above post rather than post the code here